# How to fix a ticket with a commit in Fossil

Tags: fossil

So, I think in Redmine/Git it is possible to fix an issue using the commit comment:

```
git commit -m "Fixes #123"
```

Is something like this possible in Fossil? How?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To associate a commit and a ticket you can simply put the ID of the ticket in the commit message.

You can associate the check-in with the ticket in the same way.

In the UI they will appear as clickable links, and will have a strike through them when the status is `Closed`.

---

I don't know of a way to do change the status of a ticket just by entering a specific message, but you could say:

```
$fossil commit -m "Fixed [d4fdff0914]"
New_Version: 05cb7c01d1e9a0129fda0464bee0a7ada5244a6a
$fossil ticket set d4fdff0914 status Fixed
ticket set succeeded for UID d4fdff09148c5e5c4918a64a699d91103eeaaeef
```

and it would have the same effect.

If you're creative, it might not be too much trouble to set something up to do this automatically.